# root user "locked" phpmyadmin in localhost

Tags: mysql

in localhost i have mistakenly click on "lock" option of "root" user of phpmyadmin then im getting " mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/4151): Access denied, this account is locked" issue while trying to connect "localhost/phpmyadmin" again! how can i resolve this issue?
Thanks

I have tried by changing "user" "password" "hostname" in "config.inc.php" file but nothing works!

how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: That's not phpMyAdmin problem.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/account-locking.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL on a Mac or Linux variant , depending on which account is locked, you may still be able to connect with `sudo mysql`. If so, you can run the UPDATE query (further down) to unlock the root account. You will need to run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` or restart MySQL service for the change to take effect.

If that does not work, or you are on Windows, you can use skip-grant-tables to start the service with the authentication disabled. The location of the relevant configuration file varies with version and OS.

Typical location of configuration file for MySQL 8.0 on Windows -

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini
```

MySQL on many Linux variants will check for -

```
/etc/my.cnf
```

If it does not exist check the typical location for your Linux variant. Add the `skip-grant-tables` option in the `mysqld` section -

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
```

Now you need to restart the MySQL service -

```
# On Windows (cmd as admin)
net stop MYSQL80
net start MYSQL80

# or PowerShell as admin
Restart-Service -Name MYSQL80

# On Linux
sudo service mysql restart
```

You should now be able to connect to MySQL without needing credentials, and you can pass the UPDATE query in directly with `--execute` or `-e`.

```
mysql -e "UPDATE `mysql`.`user` SET `account_locked` = 'N' WHERE `User` = 'root';"
```

And now you can reverse the configuration changes made above and restart MySQL service again.